# Filtering Live Messenger traffic by contacts

Tags: networking, proxy, filtering, messenger

I am looking for a filtering solution to be able to filter Live Messenger traffic according "with who" they are chatting.
We use Messenger for work, but some of collegues gets a lot of "out of work" messages during work time.

I would like to restrict the messenger traffic according to the contacts email, or UID.

I have found a possible solution, but I couldn't even start it, and seems a bit outdated.
msnpr.exe from http://3proxy.ru/download/

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options...

[Smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.net) (bias alert: I work for Smoothwall) produce UTM devices that can monitor/block IM. The IM "half proxy" we use is called [imspector](http://www.imspector.org) (bias alert: I have a tiny bit of code in there, and the dev is a colleague and friend), which if you want to implement it on its own might offer more flexibility at a cost of having to set it all up yourself.

Another option is to use an [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) server. We use this to bridge our internal SIP messaging to MSN. Getting it to talk MSN is a bit of a bind IIRC, needing a hard to track down 3rd party plugin, I think this [kraken](http://kraken.blathersource.org) business was involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find an app to handle it, you'll have to get messy with the messenger protocols to be able to pull the contact's information out before delivery. The protocols seem to be updated frequently to continuously cripple unofficial clients, so it's probably impractical.

MS offers a corporate alternative to live messenger which was forked from Windows Messenger, [MS Office Communicator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Communicator). This is the non-hacky way to restrict your messenger use to business purposes.

Alternatively, you could deploy a Jabber server or something similar if you're on a budget.

Lastly, don't forget the maxim "You shouldn't attempt to solve people problems with technology alone"